# Get item clicked and passing to another class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a foods.dart like so

```
List<Map> foods = [
{
"img": "assets/food1.jpg",
"name": "burger"
},
{
"img": "assets/food2.jpg",
"name": "fries"
},
];
```

I then have my CarouselSlider like so

```
CarouselSlider(
options: CarouselOptions(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2.4,
autoPlay: true,//
viewportFraction: 1.0,
onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
setState(() {
_current = index;
});
}
),
items: map<Widget>(
foods,
(index, i){
Map food = foods[index];
return SliderItem(
img: food['img'],
name: food['name'],
);
},
).toList(),
),
```

And my slider.dart

```
class SliderItem extends StatelessWidget {
final String name;
final String img;
//final bool isFav;
//final double rating;
//final int raters;
SliderItem({
Key key,
@required this.name,
@required this.img})
//@required this.isFav,
//@required this.rating,
//@required this.raters})
:super(key: key);
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return InkWell(
child: ListView(
shrinkWrap: true,
primary: false,
children: <Widget>[
Stack(
children: <Widget>[
Container(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.2,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
child: ClipRRect(
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
child: Image.asset(
"$img",
fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
),
),
Positioned(
right: -10.0,
bottom: 3.0,
child: RawMaterialButton(
onPressed: (){},
elevation: 4.0,
child: Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
),
),
),
],
),
Padding(
padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2.0, top: 8.0),
child: Text(
"$name",
style: TextStyle(
fontSize: 20.0,
fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
),
maxLines: 2,
),
),
],
),
onTap: (){
Navigator.of(context).push(
MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (BuildContext context){
return ProductDetails();
},
),
);
},
);
}
}
```

My question is how do I get which image was selected and pass it to ProductDetails page ?

Is it best to pass the image name index?

Iam not to sure which is the best method

I hope I've been clear enough.
I am using carousel_slider: ^2.1.0
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass object to another widget in navigation like this:

```dart
onTap: () {
        Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return ProductDetails(
                name: name,
                img: img,
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      },
```

then in **ProductDetails** widget you can get parameter like this:

```dart
class ProductDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final String img;

  const ProductDetails({Key key, @required this.name, @required this.img})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            "$name",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 20.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
            ),
            maxLines: 2,
          ),
          Image.asset(
            "$img",
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

But the best solution is you create a class like **Food** then you used **ListView.builder** for list of foods then you create a widget for each item of foods like **SliderItem** with callback and into callback in list navigate to **ProductDetails** with food object.

But Problem is **CarouselSlider** take an **items** like list of widget and you can not use **ListView.builder**, so you have bad performance in big list of foods.
https://youtu.be/vVg9It7cOfY